# What will PR-2149 offer?

Tags: eth-2.0, staking

I've seen this [PR-2149](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/pull/2149) quite a few times already and people are saying this is big for Ethereum 2.0. Can someone explain in simpler terms what will it offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting an answer from the ethstaker Discord channel:

> This PR allows a contract to be the recipient of the withdrawn ETH instead of a person who could potentially take the ETH and run away. Staking pools can therefore have an ETH1 contract handle the withdrawal keys.